# Quadratic Resizing a Grid Pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx, resize, gridpane

I am working on a game called pentago. After the user has occupied a field, the user has to rotate one of the four quadrants.

The problem is that after the user has resized the window, the four quadrants are not quadratic anymore. And with non quadratic quadrant the animation will not work.

I am searching for a solution that keeps a gridpane quadratic (quadratic Resizing) while resizing the JavaFX window.

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the scene structure. Maybe you can even rewrite the animation. Right now it's hard to tell what's breaking your animation...

Comment: Please make a [mcve] if you want more help